# How do you change the line-spacing of an attributed UILabel in Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uistoryboard, nsattributedstring

It's easy enough to do in code, but if I create a UILabel in a Storyboard and set it to attributed text, then change the Spacing or the Line Height properties, neither has any effect on the label's line-spacing when I run the application.

How do I change the line-spacing in a Storyboard?

Comment: It worked when I did it. You need to explain what steps you took in setting up your label.

Comment: You may have to select the part of the text you want before doing the change.